# How to implement two authentication layers in django

Tags: django, database, django-models, authentication

I have a web application for businesses. Upon login, a user (the manager of the business) can view tables with information about their business.

userID 1->* rows in a MasterTable,

userID 1->* rows in a ForecastTable

I need to change it so an owner of multiple businesses can log into the account for a specific business and edit the same information that the manager can.

I was thinking about changing the database schema to something like this:
userID *-* businessID 1-* rows in MasterTable, rows in ForecastTable

Should I have 2 login pages, first for the userID, then the businessID.  Then all the columns in the database only reference the businessID, so different users can edit the same data.

Or the same login form makes the user enter a businessID, and their username, then depending on which businessID they enter, it logs into that page?

I'm not sure what is the best practice to implement something like this.

Here is what my django model looks like:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MasterEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    cutoff1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cutoff2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rooms_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_blackout = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ForecastEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

A user has hundreds of these 'master entry' and 'forecast entry' rows.  I query the database for the rows and create a table in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two layers of authentication.

For instance, a user which is not admin only can view business he owns, this is achieved with a simple filter in the view displayed the mentioned list of business.

And you could render each business name as a link that then shows a list of `MasterEntry`s in it.

This is more a problem with information layout.

Conclusion:

1. Show a page only with business belonging to the authenticated user.
2. Superuser can see all business.
3. You can click a business entry in order to view/edit/delete any of the `MasterEntry`s it contains.

Comment: I actually have 2 tables.  MasterEntry and ForecastEntry which are displayed in 2 different views.  I edited the original post to show this. This is why I thought I would need a separate login, because switching between views should only show information about that business.  Would this logic still work? I would need a way for Superuser to switch between businesses.

Comment: Think about this: why would need a business owner authenticate to other thing than his own business directly?

Comment: I understand conceptually.  The 'users' table would have a many-to-many relationship with a 'business' table. Then the 'businesses' table would have a one-to-many relationship with a 'ForecastEntry' table and a 'MasterEntry' table.  
The problem I have is when a business owner wants to switch between businesses.  The ForecastEntry table and MasterEntry table are on separate web pages.  Since there is no 'logout' functionality between businesses, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Check the section `Using SingleObjectMixin with ListView` here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/